# select_related and prefetch_related django

Tags: django

I have these 4 models:

```
class User(models.Model):
    user = ...

class Subject(models.Model):
    subject = ...

class Section(models.Model):
    section= ...

class Profile(models.Model):
    user= ...

class student(models.Model):
    student = foreignkey(User)
    enrolled_subjects = ManyToMany(Subject)
    section = foreignkey(Section)
    profile = foreignkey(Profile)
```

how can I get all related objects to `Student` object using `select_related` and `prefetch_related`? Thank you

UPDATE:

proof that I have selected enrolled_subjects for a certain student:

[image]

but when I do this:

```
    one_student = Student.objects.get(student__username="jun.moicel.zuniga")
    print(one_student.enrolled_subjects)
```

```
[15/Aug/2021 09:14:48] "GET /static/js/students/addgrades.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
1
<QuerySet [<Subject: Filipino 1, (FIL01), for Grade 7>, <Subject: Math 1, (MATH01), for Grade 7>, <Subject: Science 1, (sci01), for Grade 7>]>
main.Subject.None
[15/Aug/2021 09:14:49] "GET /students/upload-grade/98/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8103
```

still main.Subject.None, the subject list on server log was from this code:

```
    one_student = Student.objects.get(student__username="jun.moicel.zuniga")
    print(one_student.enrolled_subjects.all())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- use `select_related(fieldname)` to load objects *referenced directly from this model* by a foreign key (many2one)
- use `prefetch_related(fieldname)` to load objects referenced indirectly (object *that have references to this model*)

  - by one2many (that means, this object is referenced from another model by some foreign key)
  - by many2many (that's your case - both `Student` and `Subject` are referenced from an intermediate technical model)

```py
qs = Student.objects.select_related(
    'student', 'section', 'profile',
).prefetch_related(
    'enrolled_subjects',
)
```

---

How to add filters on a related field - just use filter as usual, but prefix names of fields on a related model with a name of referrer field.

Example:

Let's say, we need to get such `Student`s, that they have such `Section`s, that their `section` is 'example'.

How do we do that in python:

```py
Student.objects.filter(section__section='example')
#                 (1)->^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^<-(2)
```

1. the name of field on the `Student` model
2. the name of field on the `Section` model

You're free combine prefetches, selects and filters in any order.

```py
Student.objects.filter(...).prefetch_related(...).select_related(...).filter(...)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering, it works. but I need a little bit more. How can I add a filter on each select_related()? @madbird

Comment: I need to insert `.filter(section__adviser_id=pk)`, how can I do this?

Comment: do i need to set `through` in my related fields? @madbird

Comment: No, you don't need to set `through` yet.

Comment: Im sorry Sir, but I cant make it to work, i tried this code `    my_students = Student.objects.filter(section__id=teacher_section.id).select_related(
        "section", "profile",
        ).prefetch_related("enrolled_subjects")`

With the code written above I am getting main.Subject.None
 @madbird

Comment: I am getting Student Objets filtered with section id but i am not getting enrolled_subjects @madbird

Comment: Try reduced variant: `Student.objects.filter(section=teacher_section).select_related( "section", "profile").prefetch_related("enrolled_subjects")`. If this won't work, I guess, we'll need to see a traceback to understand what's wrong. In such case, better to update the question, or create a new one.

Comment: I am not getting a traceback but i am getting an object of main.Subject.None @madbird

Comment: Enrolled subjects should appear on each `Student` record, accessible by `student.enrolled_subjects` field. If you're getting None, you probably did not add any subjects to a student. that's it.

Comment: Please check the updated answer, I showed a picture in database that there are selected items for enrolled_subjects, but still i get main.Subject.None @madbird

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236012/discussion-between-madbird-and-jem).

Comment: thank you, posted an answer with whats missing. Your answer is still right. thanks!!!! @madbird

Answer (score 0):

@madbird 's answer is right, we are just missing .all()

```
    my_students = Student.objects.filter(section=teacher_section).prefetch_related("enrolled_subjects").select_related(
        "section", "profile",
        )
    print(my_students[1].enrolled_subjects.all())
```